# If ElseIf Else + Nested If is throwing Expected End error

Tags: vbscript

My gigantic nested conditional below:

```
Function getArrayOpt(ByVal cb1, ByVal cb2)
    If boolAS1 = True And boolAS2 = True Then
        If mon1 = "D" Then
            getArrayOpt = Array(cb1, cb2)
        Else If mon2 = "S" Then
            getArrayOpt = Array(cb1, cb2, vbNullString)
        Else
            getArrayOpt = Array(cb1, cb2, st(0), st(1))
        End If
    ElseIf boolAS1 = True And boolAS2 = False Then 
        If mon1 = "D" Then
            getArrayOpt = Array(cb1, cb2)
        Else If mon2 = "S" Then
            getArrayOpt = Array(cb1, vbNullString)
        Else
            getArrayOpt = Array(cb1, cb2, st(0))
        End If
    ElseIf boolAS1 = False And boolAS2 = True Then
        If mon1 = "D" Then
            getArrayOpt = Array(cb1, cb2)
        Else If mon2 = "S" Then
            getArrayOpt = Array(cb2, vbNullString)
        Else
            getArrayOpt = Array(cb1, cb2, st(0), st(1))
        End If
    Else
        If mon1 = "D" Then
            getArrayOpt = Array(cb1, cb2)
        Else If mon2 = "S" Then
            getArrayOpt = Array(cb1)
        Else
            getArrayOpt = Array(cb2, st(0), st(1))
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

The thing is, I don't know why it's throwing "Expected End". I looked everywhere in the code, tried a bunch of stuff but still it keeps throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna kill myself here, I'll comeback in a while. The problem was the first nested if had an else if which wasn't right:

```
Function getArrayOpt(ByVal cb1, ByVal cb2)
If boolAS1 = True And boolAS2 = True Then
If mon1 = "D" Then
    getArrayOpt = Array(cb1, cb2)
```

Here would be "Else If mon2 = "S" Then" at the original code, but the right is "ElseIf":

```
ElseIf mon2 = "S" Then
    getArrayOpt = Array(cb1, cb2, vbNullString)

Else
    getArrayOpt = Array(cb1, cb2, st(0), st(1))

End If

ElseIf boolAS1 = True And boolAS2 = False Then 
If mon1 = "D" Then
    getArrayOpt = Array(cb1, cb2)

Else If mon2 = "S" Then
    getArrayOpt = Array(cb1, vbNullString)

Else
    getArrayOpt = Array(cb1, cb2, st(0))

End If

ElseIf boolAS1 = False And boolAS2 = True Then
If mon1 = "D" Then
    getArrayOpt = Array(cb1, cb2)

Else If mon2 = "S" Then
    getArrayOpt = Array(cb2, vbNullString)

Else
    getArrayOpt = Array(cb1, cb2, st(0), st(1))

End If

Else
If mon1 = "D" Then
    getArrayOpt = Array(cb1, cb2)

Else If mon2 = "S" Then
    getArrayOpt = Array(cb1)

Else
    getArrayOpt = Array(cb2, st(0), st(1))

End If

End If
End Function
```